# Show run & debug toolbar in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

How do I get this run & debug toolbar to show in PyCharm? It shows in some of my projects, but not others.

And, in the spirit of teaching a man to fish, is there an easy way to find this using PyCharm's own help facility?

[image]

Comment: You try `Run -> Edit configurations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lukassz commented above, if you want to have the run/debug toolbar, you have to edit your run/debug configuration:

**The manual way:**

Go to Run > Edit Configuration > Hit the `+` sign on the top left of the subsequent window > Create a new run configuration.

**The semi-automatic way:**

With the file that you want to run, open on your editor, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (if you are using the default keymap) or Run > Run/Debug . 
On the subsequent pop-up window, choose the file to run and PyCharm will (try to) run it for you. 
In the process, a configuration will be generated, which persists.

**The fishing lesson:** Here is a [pond with fish](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/working-with-run-debug-configurations.html) and the tools to [catch the fish](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) in question.

Happy fishing and good luck :D

Answer (score 1):

I was able to show the 'Run Configurations' toolbar by selecting **View / Appearance / Toolbar**.

[image]

If you right-click on the Toolbar, you can access 'Customize Menus and Toolbars' for further customisation.

- [More information on customizing Pycharm toolbars](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/customize-actions-menus-and-toolbars.html)